# How to code a second function in the new Input System's button Fire?

Tags: c#, android, iphone, windows, unity-game-engine

I'm making a small game and I'd like to cast this purple skull spell when I press the down button on right side.
I already have a spell cast but I wish a second function. How to code that ?

I'm expecting a help
There's an Attack() linked to the new input system but I wish a second attack with a diferente button.

Comment: I havent seen the new Input system come with any presets, ive always had to make my own.  So i cant help but think you mean the old system.. Also, this is not that clear as to exactly what youre trying to do, or what you did to try

Comment: @ManuelNeto Please add some details showing what you have done.